# Equivalent formula in countable structures

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Question, if two sentences A & B, are such that for all countable structures M: M⊨A iff M⊨B, and A & B be thus logically eguivalent. But how?!

I understand that I have to use Löwenheim-Skolem theory, and I have seen the proof of that there is a phi that M'⊨phi and M⊨phi then M and M' are isomorphic.But from that I can not decuce an answer. How should I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be the sentence $(A\longrightarrow B)\land (B\longrightarrow A)$. By hypothesis, $\phi$ is true in all countable $L$-structures, for an appropriate language $L$.

Then $\phi$ is true in all $L$-structures. For by Lowenheim-Skolem, if the sentence $\lnot\phi$ had a model, it would have a countable model.

Since $\phi$ is true in all $L$-structures, the sentences $A$ and $B$ are logically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! bur i still do not understand one thing: What does the Löwenheim-Skolem add in this question? It is given that A,B satisfy all countable models?

Comment: Completeness tells us $\phi$ is a theorem if and only if $\phi$ is true in all structures. Lowenheim-Skolem tells us that if there is a structure in which $\phi$ is false, then there is a **countable** structure in which $\phi$ is false. But we are told that $\phi$ is true in all countable structures. So it must be true in all structures.